# Convert Data to Oracle Data

Tags: oracle, timezone, oracle12c, utc, timezone-offset

I am receiving this date from a WS `2017-12-03T05:44:57` , that I want to convert to Oracle Date, but I don't `T05` but refers exactly.

```
TZD Daylight savings information. For example, 'PST' ?
TZH Time zone hour. ?
TZM Time zone minute. ?
TZR Time zone region. ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2017-12-03T05:44:57` is according to [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. `T` is the separator between date and time values (actually often it is skipped - and thus not strictly according to the standard)

`2017-12-03T05:44:57` does not contain any time information, i.e. you don't know the time zone.

Time zone information are provided for example as `2017-12-03T05:44:57+08:00` or `2017-12-03T05:44:57Z` for UTC times.

Conversion to a DATE/TIMESTAMP would be like this

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE('2017-12-03T05:44:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-03T05:44:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual;
```